# I cannot able to find com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class (I have added mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar to my path by using Eclipse build path)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I did following steps trying use jdbc:
1) Downloaded mysql connector and copied mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar to my project folder.
2) Add the same jar to classpath by using Eclipse build path option.
3) Wrote following code:

```
import java.sql.*;


class Solution{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Connection con; // The JDBC provided connection object.

        Class.forName(“com.mysql.jdbc.Driver”).newInstance(); // Error - com.mysql.jdbc.Driver cannot be resolved to a variable

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That error indicates a probable hidden character in line 10. Try cutting and re-pasting the code or re-typing the line to see if that solves the issue.

Comment: It was the problem of inverted commas. Thank you.

Comment: You haven't needed that line of code since 2007. Remove it.